# Assigning values to array in for loops shows weird behaviour in C

Tags: arrays, c, performance, for-loop, gcc

Hello and sorry for the bad title.

I have this code snippet and here's my problem:

My code takes about ~1.3 s to run, with the addition of `#pragma omp parallel for` I managed to decrease the runtime to ~0.2 s.

I am assuming that my bottleneck is the last line in the for loop `theta_rec[i] = (1.0 / 4.0) * atan2(sum_i, sum_r) - M_PI / 4;`

When I remove this line my code runs in 0.0 s.

After some trial and error this is what I found out:

I tried to just compute the expression I am assigning to `theta[i]` and assign it to a variable like `double tmp = (1.0 / 4.0) * atan2(sum_i, sum_r) - M_PI / 4;` which is commented out in the code below. This also results in a runtime of 0.0 s. Contrarily when I take this variable and assign it back to `theta[i]` like `theta_rec[i] = tmp;`, again commented out in the code below, the code runs in 0.2s.

Even weirder is the fact that if I just assign a random double value `theta_rec[i] = 1.2;` the code also still runs in 0.0 s.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
void test(double* sigs_in_r, double* sigs_in_i, int Nsig, int nCPE, double* theta_rec) {
    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < Nsig; i++) {
        int start = i - nCPE > 0 ? i - nCPE : 0;
        int stop = i + nCPE < Nsig - 2 ? i + nCPE : Nsig - 2;
        double sum_r = 0.0;
        double sum_i = 0.0;

        for (int j = start; j <= stop; j++) {
            double sigs_in_r_j = sigs_in_r[j];
            double sigs_in_i_j = sigs_in_i[j];
            double abs_val = sqrt(sigs_in_r_j * sigs_in_r_j + sigs_in_i_j * sigs_in_i_j);
            double arg_val = atan2(sigs_in_i_j, sigs_in_r_j);
            double abs_val_pow4 = abs_val * abs_val * abs_val * abs_val;
            sum_r += abs_val_pow4 * cos(4 * arg_val);
            sum_i += abs_val_pow4 * sin(4 * arg_val);
        }
        theta_rec[i] = (1.0 / 4.0) * atan2(sum_i, sum_r) - M_PI / 4;
        //double tmp = (1.0 / 4.0) * atan2(sum_i, sum_r) - M_PI / 4;
        //theta_rec[i] = tmp;
        //theta_rec[i] = 1.2;
    }
}
```

My main function for testing:

```
#define SIZE 100000
int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    double *arr1 = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double *arr2 = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));

    double *theta = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        arr1[i] = 1.0;
        arr2[i] = 2.0;
    }

    start = clock(); // Start the timer

    test(arr1, arr2, SIZE, 100, theta);

    end = clock(); // Stop the timer

    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // Calculate the CPU time used in seconds

    printf("Computation time: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

My header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
```

I compile like that:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -Ofast -fopenmp -std=c99 test.c -o test`

Comment: If you don't assign to `theta_rec[i]` there is no observable behavior from the `test` function. It doesn't do anything useful, and its contents can be optimized away by the compiler. Look at [the generated assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/Mz943bPPs) and it's basically what's happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but assigning the calculation to a `double` variable or assigning a set value to  `theta_rec[i]` is also very fast even though something is happening

Comment: That's because all the calculations are optimized away since they're not needed. Assigning a simple constant value is fast. doing all the calculations are not.

Comment: "When I remove this line my code runs in 0.0 s." Yeah because then your function no longer has any side effects and can be replaced with a `NOP`.

Comment: Okay I understand thanks. Are there any recommendations for optimizations?

Comment: @BradLanam I don't know what you mean I am using `sqrt(a*a + b*b)`

Comment: The compiler should re-use `4 * arg_val`, but I would still set `arg_val = 4.0 * atan2 (..., ...)` and adjust the `cos()` and `sin()` calls.  Also change `M_PI / 4` to `M_PI / 4.0`.  You are working with doubles, use doubles.   Less chance of conversion weirdness, better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> When I remove this line my code runs in 0.0 s.

Yes because then it has no side effects any longer. The generated machine code becomes:

```
test:
    ret
```

---

> I tried to just compute the expression I am assigning to theta[i] and assign it to a variable like `double tmp = (1.0 / 4.0) * atan2(sum_i, sum_r) - M_PI / 4;`

Same thing, no side effects, just a local variable. Change it to `volatile double tmp` and you'll notice about the same performance as when you wrote to `theta_rec`.

---

> Contrarily when I take this variable and assign it back to theta[i] like theta_rec[i] = tmp;, again commented out in the code below, the code runs in 0.2s.

Yeah because now the side effect of updating a value outside the function is back again. `tmp` however will get optimized out and never allocated.

---

Misc advise for benchmarking is to always disassemble the code to see what was actually generated. Even if you don't know assembler well.

Another thing to consider is that desktop OS may use delayed heap allocation. As in the OS might not make the actual kernel API call until the point where that memory is actually used for the first time. Meaning your benchmarking could go bananas if you think you left the malloc/calloc calls out of it but actually didn't. You can solve this by "touching" a random cell in the allocated chunk by a `volatile` access or similar, forcing the OS to actually go ahead and alloc before the benchmarking has started.

Other than that, fairly complex floating point calculations on a large chunk of data is an excellent use-case for parallelization, so it isn't surprising if you can get a performance increase when adding more threads.

Some further micro-optimizations may be possible by writing a proper function with *const correctness* and also adding `restrict` to the read/write data:

```
void test (const double*     sigs_in_r, 
           const double*     sigs_in_i, 
           int               Nsig, 
           int               nCPE, 
           double* restrict  theta_rec);
```

Ditching `int` in favour for `int_fast32_t` might possibly also enable some micro-optimizations on 64 CPUs.